# keras "All layer names should be unique" error while using optuna hyperparameters optimizer with number of jobs

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow2.0

I'm using optuna package to optimize my model, and I'm using the option to run multiple job at a time. when I ran this I get:

```
Trial  failed because of the following error: ValueError('The name "dense" is used 3 times in the model. All layer names should be unique.'
```

But I didn't assign any names to the layers. I had the `tensorflow.keras.backend.clear_session()`, and when I remove it I don't get the error anymore. is this ok to remove it? what are the impacts? is there other solution to this?

Comment: Layers name should be unique, for more clarification, you should share your model.

Comment: @ashraful , As I said, I didn't give any names to the layers, keras is creating them automatically. when I using only job, I don't get the error. I can't provide the model as the code is complicated to understand and it contains a lot of modules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
tf.keras.backend.reset_uids()
```

is all you need.

Answer (score 1):

Based on similar experiences on a GPU-trained model in tensorflow, you are dealing with the fact that GPU memory is not automatically cleared out like CPU RAM.  I would suggest the following solution (please let me know if it does not work):

```
from tensorflow.keras.backend import clear_session
import gc
```

and then call `clear_session()` before you define any `algorithm_model` that will be used for a cross-validation run.  Also, at the end of that run/replicate, after you have returned the objective function score, call the following two lines to clear out your memory:

```
gc.collect()
del algorithm_model
```

For more details on a cross-validation that did not use Optuna, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61252435/12763497) answer to a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50895110/12763497).  And no, you cannot get rid of the call to `clear_session()` because that is what clears the model off your GPU memory!

Comment: Here is an example of using Optuna where they keep the clear_session() call: https://medium.com/@Minyus86/optkeras-112bcc34ec73 (note, they are using keras, not tf.keras, which appaently causes problems, so you might have to edit their code.